# Kendo grid: Validate empty cells at bulk update

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

User can enter values into several rows and save the changes by clicking update button outside of the grid. However I would not like to allow saving rows with even a single empty cell. Is there an easy way is kendo grid to validate against empty cells in a row during saving? I need to show a warning message if an empty cell is found.

Answer (score 0):

You could define those fields as required in the [schema model](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#model.define) of the data source for that grid. Here's a trivial example (shortened for brevity).

---

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  schema: {
    model: {
      id: 'id',
      fields: {
        name: { 
          type: 'string',
          validation: { required: true }  \\ this will enable validation
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

var $grid = $('#grid').kendoGrid({
  dataSource: ds
});
```

Comment: Hello @Brett. Thanks, but this is not really the solution of my problem. The point is that in my case I can edit all the rows simultaneously and finally when I hit update button, I need some validator to check if there are empty cells in all these rows. Is that possible with kendo grid?

Comment: @KarenGumerov The Kendo validator should do that automatically if you set the fields as required. This is a common behavior and the framework supports it, so, I don't understand what else could be the issue. Without further information, code, or images that illustrate what you're trying to do, I'm afraid I can't help further.